# Operador ternário retorna error 500

Tags: php

Eu queria que na condição sempre que o `input text` for igual a um valor desative o `input radio`, mas retorna sempre error 500 ao executar na página:

```
$y = 0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {   
    $property = ($rows_cursos["Descricao"] === "1 Desinfetante de Surpeficies" || $rows_cursos["Descricao"] === "Saco/Caixa c/ Cotonetes") : "disabled" ? "required";
    $tabela1 .= '<tr>';
    $tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" readonly="true" size="20" name= "Produto['.$y.']" class= "Produto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'"></td>';
    $tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Ok" '.$property.'></td>';
    $tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" '.$property.'></td>';
    $tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
    $y++;
}
```

Comment: Esse codigo funciona sem o operador ternário?

Comment: @Bruno Romualdo sim funciona, o problema é quando adiciono `:"disabled"?"required"`

Comment: não se esqueça de marcar uma resposta como correta, e aconselho que enquanto estiver aprendendo algo novo sempre pesquise e escreva você mesmo o código pois assim você grava melhor e pode ajudar outros quando precisarem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erro 500 é um erro interno do servidor. Para saber onde está o erro você precisa ativar o log de erros no servidor ou ativar o display errors no script, colocando o seguinte código no inicio:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

No seu caso o erro está no operador ternário. É um erro muito comum trocar a posição do `:` com o `?`. Da documentação:

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.

Alterando a linha 5 do seu código deve resolver o erro 500.

```
$property = ($rows_cursos["Descricao"]==="1 Desinfetante de Surpeficies" || $resultado_cursos["Descricao"]==="Saco/Caixa c/ Cotonetes") ? "disabled" : "required";
```

Uma dica é pensar na `expr1` como uma pergunta. Isso faz lembrar que no final tem o ponto de interrogação.

Answer (score 2):

Ta errado a ordem amigo, operador é assim:

```
condição ? resultado_verdadeiro : resultado_falso
```

você colocou o `?` no lugar do `:`.